# GCP Multiple VPC networks in same region but different zone need to connect on-premise network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc, google-cloud-vpn, on-premises-instances

We have multiple VPC networks with respect to the env type, like dev/sit/e2e/pre-prod/prod etc to isolate the workload. Each VPC network having multiple subnets. The core applications are built using the GCP services like GCE, GKE, Cloud Storage, Load balancer etc. The underlying databases of the application are still in the on-premise network and yet to be migrated in the GCP due to various issues. For Test/Dev env we are planning to use HA-VPN to communicate with the on-premise database and for prod & pre-prod we will use dedicated interconnect.

For our non-production & production env, we are evaluating the Hub & Spoke architecture where all the spoke VPC will connect to the Hub and the Hub VPC will connect to the on-premise network using either HA VPN or Dedicated Interconnect.

I'm not able to find out any good document or step by step guide to facilitate this architecture. If you can share your knowledge regarding how we can connect multiple VPC network with on-prem in most simplest way, it would be very much helpful for me.

I'm relative new on the GCP hybrid cloud architecture and we need to do PoC before providing the solution to the customer.

Thank you!!!

Setting up HA-VPN for each VPC may not be good solution. Need more precise way to connect multiple VPC network to On-prem network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you look into [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc), although I don't know how feasible it is for you to make the switch now.  But essentially it consists of a centrally managed VPC (your host project) in which you can create subnets and assign to other projects (called service projects) to use.  So you can create a single VPN from your host project to your on-prem and have your service projects share it.

Comment: In extension of that answer, you can check the Hub and Spoke architecture pattern on Google Cloud here: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploy-hub-spoke-vpc-network-topology

Comment: Thank You Glen. Apart from configuring the shared VPC  between host project & service project,  is there any other alternative ? Like VPC peering between Hub & Spoke networks and from the Hub network establish the HA-VPN/Dedicated interconnect ? I believe we need to configure some sort of routes to send the traffic from Spoke network to On-prem via Hub network using interconnect. Do you have any sample architecture or document to achieve the architecture like this ?

Answer (score 0):

an easy and secure option is to use Aviatrix to build out the hub and spoke architecture. Hub VPC is connected to on prem and you can Macro or micro segment spoke to spoke and/or spoke to on prem traffic. You can also do everything as code so setting it up for a test can be done in a couple of minutes - here’s an example of the hub tf module:  https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aviatrix-modules/mc-transit/aviatrix/latest

Here’s an example of the spoke module:  https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aviatrix-modules/mc-spoke/aviatrix/latest

In addition you get lots of visibility into types of traffic passing over your hub and spokes, can run reports, etc